# Table responsiveness in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design

So. I am creating a small site to test my capabilities.
In my site i have a page that in Firefox looks like this:

[image]

The additional files and additional actions buttons are inside a table. and each button is inside a `<td>` which are set to appear one under another with CSS using `display:block;` on the `<td>` element.

The problem is that when i open the page in IE9 or lower the td's are shown inline like this:

[image]

Because of this the responsiveness of the page is broken and resizing the viewport will move the page content below the left menu...

Here is the HTML of the tables:

```
<table class="buttons">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Additional files:</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <a id="cv" href="">Curriculum Vitae</a>
          </td>
          <td>
             <a id="cover" href="">Cover Letter</a>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="buttons">        
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <th colspan="3">Additional actions:</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <a class="approve" href="">Denie</a>
             <span style="display: none;">31</span>
          </td>
          <td>
             <a href="" class="mailto">Reply</a>
          </td>
          <td>
             <a href="" class="link-fain delete-app">Delete</a>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.buttons {
    float: left;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    width: 50%;
}
.buttons td {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using a css reset?

Comment: Nope. I don't really know what it does...

Comment: This isn't tabular data so from a semantic point of view you shouldn't be using a table to mark up this content. Perhaps if you found an alternative way of marking up this page you would find it easier to manipulate in a responsive way.

Comment: I think that if you change the td's into blocks, you should also change the display of the table and the tr's. Otherwise you end up with non-table content in a table, and browsers may react differently to that.

Comment: http://www.cssreset.com/ Basically each browser has it's own predefined styling, in order to make sure your site is displayed the same on all of them you use a css reset.
As @MrMisterMan highlighted you shouldn't be using tables unless it is for tabular data.

Comment: is it correct to use lists than? or should i jus use divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer here is that you shouldn't be using `<table>` tags for this. What you have there is not a table, and so `<table>` is not semantically correct.

It's even worse because you're then overriding the default table layout by using `display:block`, which moves us even further away from wanting to use a `<table>`.

By using tables like this, and forcing the browser to restructure it with CSS, you're making it quite confusing for the browser. Particularly with the `colspan` attributes and then three columns of buttons, when you actually want them all in one column. Its easy to see why you'd get inconsistent behaviour with this, especially with older browsers.

So the solution here is to swap your `<table>` layout for a set of `<div>` elements. This will be semantically correct, and it will be easier to get it styled consistently. And you'll need less markup as well.

If you *really* want to carry on using tables for this layout, then you need to re-style *all* the elements -- `display:block` on the `tr` elements doesn't affect the display property of the `table`, `tbody` and `tr` elements, and these would also need to changed. But really, I would avoid that. Just use `div`s; it'll make things much cleaner.

Comment: i already edited it using `<ul>` and it works perfectly. Is it correct or should i change it to divs :)

Comment: @BeniaminSzabo: `<ul>` is fine

Comment: @BeniaminSzabo - Yep, use `ul`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `table-layout: fixed;` to your table and if still not working add a div inside td and manage the css which might work.